# Javascript Regex with Special Character and Space

Tags: javascript, regex

By using Javascript, I want to convert text

```
"  [a] b    [c]"
```

to

```
"[a] b [c]"
```

My code as below:

```
var test = "  [a] b    [c]";
test.replace(/\s+\[/g, "[");
alert(test);
```

However, the result is

```
"[a] b    [c]"
```

I wonder why? Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: @raina77ow Check the source by clicking on `edit`.

Comment: I don't know why stack overflow override my post. my result is "[a] b    [c]"

Comment: @SantiagoMunez It's HTML, HTML ! Multiple spaces = 1 space !

Comment: Ouh! Thanks! Any idea why? I think the problem is with my regex >.<

Comment: I don't think that's the right answer at all.  Strings are immutable.  No way could the first two spaces of `test` have been changed.  Something is strange here.

Comment: Also, use `console.log` rather than relying on `alert`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable. So `replace` doesn't change `test` but returns a changed string. Hence, you need to assign the result:

```
test = test.replace(/\s+\[/g, "[");
```

Note that this will result in `[a] b[c]`. To get your actual result, you might want to use:

```
test = test.replace(/(^|\s)\s*\[/g, "$1[");
```

This makes sure to write back the first of the space characters if it was not at the beginning of the string.

Alternatively, use `trim` first and write back one space manually:

```
test = test.trim().replace(/\s+\[/g, " [");
```

Comment: Yes, but now I wonder why did the string change in the OP example. )

Comment: @raina77ow because he didn't see the leading spaces in the alert box (if they were rendered at all)

Comment: Argh, but of course. @SantiagoMunez - make a habit using `console.log` instead of `alert` to debug things. )

Comment: Thanks! It works. Btw, do you mind to also explain the expression? 
test = test.replace(/(^|\s)\s*\[/g, "$1[");
why my expression \s+ is not enough to achieve the objective that I want?

Comment: Why are you bothering with matching the `[` at all?

Comment: This also **fails** if there is more than one space after `]`;

Comment: @naomik because the OP apparently only wants to normalise spaces in front of `[`. at least he never mentioned anything else.

Comment: @SantiagoMunez your attempt matches all spaces in front of all `[` and doesn't write any back. hence, you are just removing all spaces (see my example output). if you just added a space into the replacement (as in my last example) that would leave a leading space at the beginning of the string. hence, my second pattern makes sure that you either match the start of the string and capture nothing - or a single space anywhere else in the string - and writes it back with `$1`, so that through that condition you always get the right behaviour.

Comment: @m.buettner, well I guess we're both wrong. The OP never explicitly said that he wanted to "normalize spaces only in front of `[`". I would argue that your solution is more specific, more rigid, and therefore not as good.

Comment: @naomik well, I inferred that from the OP's own attempt. also even the question's title mentions the "special character". his opinion would help here.

Answer (score 1):

**Trim**

```
test = test.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, test);
```

Or you can use [`str.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) if your browser supports it

```
test = test.trim();
```

note: if your need to support a browser that doesn't offer `str.trim`, you can always use [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

---

Compact spaces to one

```
test = test.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

---

A one-liner

```
test = test.trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

---

A couple tests

```
var cleanString = function(str) {
  console.log(str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, " "));
};

var examples = [
  "    [a]  b     [c]      ",
  " [a]    [b]    [c]   [d]",
  "[a]       b [c]         ",
  "              [a] b [c] "
];

examples.map(cleanString);
```

Output

```
[a] b [c]
[a] [b] [c] [d]
[a] b [c]
[a] b [c]
```

Comment: Thanks Naomik. Your solution is also working!